# select node in XML with specific value for parsing

Tags: .net, xml, xslt

I have below input XML and want it to convert in other output XML using XSLT.

My input XML is as below,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppSettings>
 <Plugins>
  <AssemblyName>Version=5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</AssemblyName>
  <TypeName>AAA</TypeName>
   <Version>?</Version>
   <Configuration>
    <AppData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/AppData.xsd">
     <Readers>
      <Id>1</Id>
      <Port>2500</Port>
      <Type>M100</Type>
     </Readers>
     </AppData>
    </Configuration>
   </Plugins>
  <Plugins>
  <AssemblyName>Version=5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</AssemblyName>
 <TypeName>BBB</TypeName>
 <Version>?</Version>
 <Configuration>
  <AppData xmlns="http://tempuri.org/AppData.xsd">
    <Readers>
      <Id>2</Id>
      <Port>3500</Port>
      <Type>M200</Type>
    </Readers>
  </AppData>
  </Configuration>
 </Plugins>
</AppSettings>
```

From above XML I want to select "Plugins" node which has TypeName "BBB" and use its child nodes to get below output.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <AppSettings>
  <Inputs>
   <PlugInType>M200</PlugInType>
   <Port>3500</Port>
   </Inputs>
  </AppSettings>
```

I tried using below XSLT, but not getting required output

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <AppSettings>
  <Inputs>
    <xsl:for-each select="AppSettings">
      <xsl:for-each select="//Plugins[TypeName=BBB]">
        <xsl:for-each select="Configuration/AppData/Readers">
          <PlugInType>
            <xsl:value-of select="Type"/>
          </PlugInType>
          <Port>
            <xsl:value-of select="Port"/>
          </Port>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Inputs>
  </AppSettings>
 </xsl:template>
```

Let me know where I am going wrong

Comment: "not getting required output" doesn't tell us anything about what you *are* getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two major problems with your stylesheet (and many minor ones). The two major problems are:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Plugins[TypeName=BBB]">
```

needs to be:

```
<xsl:for-each select="//Plugins[TypeName='BBB']">
```

and the fact that you ignore the namespace declared for the `AppData` element and its descendants.

Other than that, I don't think you need that many `xsl:for-each` statements. Try simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ad="http://tempuri.org/AppData.xsd"
exclude-result-prefixes="ad">

<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <AppSettings>
        <Inputs>
            <xsl:for-each select="AppSettings/Plugins[TypeName='BBB']">
                <PlugInType>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Configuration/ad:AppData/ad:Readers/ad:Type"/>
                </PlugInType>
                <Port>
                    <xsl:value-of select="Configuration/ad:AppData/ad:Readers/ad:Port"/>
                </Port>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </Inputs>
    </AppSettings>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Addendum:

> I want to iterate this xml further. I want to select "Plugins" node
>   which has TypeName "BBB" and having Readers which has port "3500".

Just add another *predicate* to the selecting expression:

```
<xsl:for-each select="AppSettings/Plugins[TypeName='BBB'][Configuration/ad:AppData/ad:Readers/ad:Port='3500']">
```

Comment: Hi Michael, one more addition. I want to iterate this xml further. I want to select "Plugins" node which has TypeName "BBB" and having Readers which has port "3500". How can we expand this XSLT further?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
  xmlns:df="http://tempuri.org/AppData.xsd" exclude-result-prefixes="df">
 <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <AppSettings>
  <Inputs>
    <xsl:for-each select="AppSettings//Plugins[TypeName='BBB']/Configuration/df:AppData/df:Readers">
          <PlugInType>
            <xsl:value-of select="df:Type"/>
          </PlugInType>
          <Port>
            <xsl:value-of select="df:Port"/>
          </Port>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </Inputs>
  </AppSettings>
 </xsl:template>
```

to take care of the `xmlns="http://tempuri.org/AppData.xsd"` in the XML.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, yes, I cleaned up the start tags of all the nested for-each but forgot to remove the end tags. Now fixed.